# Why Clustered Index Scan in this query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This query (SQL2012) execution plan shows me that Clustered Index Scan used in the internal sub-query on PK index:

```
  SELECT n3.id as node_id,x.id as id,
  (select xv.value from xv 
  --with(forceseek)  
  where xv.id=x.id) as [value]
  FROM x
  INNER JOIN n3
  ON x.[obj_id]=n3.id 
  AND n3.parent_id = '975422E0-5630-4545-8CF7-062D7DF72B6B'
```

The tables x and xv are master->details tables.

When I use hint forceseek then it shows Clustered Index Seek and query executes fast.
Why there is Scan instead of Seek? 
How to change the query to have Index Seek without the hint FORCESEEK?

UPD:
The full demo script:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/*
DROP TABLE [dbo].[xv]
DROP TABLE [dbo].[x]
DROP TABLE [dbo].[n3]
*/

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[n3](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [parent_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_n3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)
)

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[x](
    [obj_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_x] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
))

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[x]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_x_n3] FOREIGN KEY([obj_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[n3] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[x] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_x_n3]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[xv](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [value] [sql_variant] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_xv] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
))

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[xv]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_xv_x] FOREIGN KEY([id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[x] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[xv] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_xv_x]
GO

INSERT INTO n3(id,parent_id)
select newid(), '975422E0-5630-4545-8CF7-062D7DF72B6B'
GO 10

INSERT INTO n3(id,parent_id)
select newid(), '805422E0-5630-4545-8CF7-062D7DF72B6B'
GO 5

INSERT INTO x([obj_id]) 
select id from n3 where parent_id='975422E0-5630-4545-8CF7-062D7DF72B6B';


insert into xv (id, value) 
select id, cast(RAND(1) as sql_variant) from x 

--select * from x
--select * from n3

  SELECT n3.id as node_id,x.id as id,
  (select xv.value from dbo.xv 
  --with(forceseek)  
  where xv.id=x.id
  ) as [value]
  FROM dbo.x
  INNER JOIN dbo.n3
  ON x.[obj_id]=n3.id
  AND n3.parent_id = '975422E0-5630-4545-8CF7-062D7DF72B6B'


/*
DROP TABLE [dbo].[xv]
DROP TABLE [dbo].[x]
DROP TABLE [dbo].[n3]
*/

--Update statistics xv with fullscan
```

Comment: If you are interacting with every row in the table, I would imagine the query optimizer would use a scan over a seek. Also, if you copy/paste the query and run both, one with the forceseek and one without it, you will see the relative cost of the scan is lower.

Comment: There are 10*millions rows in real tables. My problem is that the real query (scan) executes 3-5 seconds and it is the reason of deadlocks. If I use the hint FORCESEEK it works <1 sec and deadlocks disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the `statistics` of `xv` table might be out of date. Update the statistics of `xv` and try running the query again.

```
Update statistics xv with fullscan
```

**Update :**

After looking at the data setup and query, For the given `parent_id` input  it is very clear that all the records in both `x` and `xv` match so it is obvious that optimizer chooses index scan instead of seek because it has fetch all the records from both `x` and `xv` table

Also the number of records is less so optimizer will prefer scan instead of seek

Comment: I have tried - no changes. I have added the full demo script (see the 1st message) which demonstrated this on the 3 new tables.

Comment: Please see my comment above.